# How to implement a lambert shader using Arnold API?

Tags: c++, shader

How to implement a Lambert shader using Arnold API? (for beginners)

This is an example to implement a constant shader.
I don't know how to implement a Lambert shader using Arnold API (integrate light and samples).

```cpp
#include <ai.h>
#include <cstring>

AI_SHADER_NODE_EXPORT_METHODS(LambertMethods);

enum LambertParameters {p_albedo};

node_parameters {
    AiParameterRGB("albedo", 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
}

node_loader {
    if (i > 0) return false;
    node->methods = LambertMethods;
    node->output_type = AI_TYPE_RGB;
    node->name = "Lambert";
    node->node_type = AI_NODE_SHADER;
    strcpy(node->version, AI_VERSION);
    return true;
}

node_initialize {}

node_update {}

shader_evaluate {
    AtColor albedo = AiShaderEvalParamRGB(p_albedo);
    sg->out.RGB = albedo;
}

node_finish {}
```

Answer (score 0):

Loop over lights in the scene.

```cpp
shader_evaluate {
    AtColor albedo = AiShaderEvalParamRGB(p_albedo);
    AtColor diffuse = AI_RGB_BLACK;
    AiLightsPrepare(sg);
    while (AiLightsGetSample(sg)) {
        if (AiLightGetAffectDiffuse(sg->Lp)) {
            float LdotN = AiV3Dot(sg->Ld, sg->N)
            diffuse += albedo * sg->Li * sg->we * AI_ONEOVERPI * max(0, LdotN);
        }
    }
    sg->out.RGB = diffuse;
}
```

Source: [Understanding GI with a basic shader](https://support.solidangle.com/display/ARP/Understanding+GI+with+a+basic+shader)